# How to safely undock a Surface Pro 3?

Tags: windows-8, bitlocker, docking-station

Maybe this is a non-issue, but I want to make sure that I don't suffer from data loss when undocking my Surface Pro 3. My setup is as follows:

I have an external hard disk connected to the docking station. It's BitLocker encrypted and set up as the target of File History (which continuously runs in the background, as far as I know).

My worry is that if I simply remove my Surface from the docking station, it might just be in the process of writing a backup copy onto the disk. In that case, undocking might (?) result in a corrupted file (or even worse, file system).

Are these concerns valid? If so, do I need to manually eject the drive before undocking?

Or would it be enough to shut the cover, or press the power button or some other magical key combination that will flush any buffers that need flushing? And how would I then know that it's safe to undock now?

Comment: If the external storage is only connected to the docking station.  You should always use the feature to safely eject external storage

Answer (score -1):

Completely answered on the this forum. site

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfpro3-surfdevice/propper-undocking-procedure-when-using-sp3-with/7e449b59-e9ae-4d9b-90e8-498a29215ede

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here too: 
http://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Although this may answer the question, you should give a more detailed description of the linked content and explain how it relates to the question. This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page goes is removed or goes offline. For more information, see [this Meta Stack Exchange post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259).

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's more or less the exact same question that I have, and it is just as unanswered - one person says it's possible to undock, others say it isn't when external drives are concerned...

Comment: I went to the URL to find the answer but it didn't really give a good answer. I want to know, especially when it comes to attached USB-drives, whether I need to put the SP3 to sleep before undocking or perhaps if there is a keyboard shortcut or similar to more easily "live undock" than to Eject expansion.

In my case I'm on Windows 10.